# CSS width: 100%; Not filling screen

Tags: html, css

I'm building a mobile website, which is supposed to be full-screen, however when loaded on a mobile device there is a white band down the right hand side of the page.

I've set margins and padding to 0, and parent containers seem to be 100% but there's still a band. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0}
html, body {height:100%;width:100%}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.BaseRectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #a7e6e0;
}

.Gradient_Rectangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), #000000);
}

.mainCarousel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 26.1%;
}

.BottomContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
}

.Bottom-Links {
  position: relative;
  height: 5%;
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-size: 3vw;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #100119;
  top: -45%;
  left: 28%;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

  <!--Header Content-->
  <div class="BaseRectangle"> 
    <!--Logo-->
    <div class="Gradient_Rectangle"> 

    </div>

  </div>

  <!--Begin main Carousel-->
  <div id="mainCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  </div> <!-- added the closing tag, you probably would have it here -->
  <!--End main Carousel-->

  <div class="BottomContainer">

    <div class="Bottom-Links">
      Contact &nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;Case studies &nbsp;&nbsp;| &nbsp;&nbsp;Legal
    </div>

  </div>
<!--Contact Section-->

<!--End content-->
</div>
```

Oddly, when the page loads, it seems to be full screen for a fraction of a second but then suddenly shrinks.

Comment: Please work on reducing your example to a [mcve]

Comment: Yeah, the less code you post the better ^

Comment: Did you try `width: 100vw` instead of percentage ?

Comment: Some mobile browsers do zoom out when the content is wider than the screen, even if you specify `initial-scale=1`. So if it only happens after a fraction of a second, I'd look for something that isn't there immediately, such as a too-large graphic, as the culprit.

Comment: Simplified as requested.  Worked out it's the div at the end with the class Bottom-Links.  If I remove that, all is well.  But can't see why that would be an issue.  Any thoughts much appreciated.